# iOS Safari Repeatedly Opens "Virus Detected" Emails

Tags: ipad, safari, virus

On my iPad 2 (running iOS 9) there's a "Virus Detected" email popping up that I can neither delete or change. No matter what I do, the "Virus Detected" email keeps opening on my screen whenever I attempt to use Safari.

I've attempted to delete the email, change the email and to close Safari but the email keeps returning and makes using the browser impossible. I have no intention to either call the provided phone number or sending this email as it directs me to do. The email is as follows:

`To:` foo@example.com

`Subject`: Warning! Virus Detected! Immediately Call Apple Support +1-800-876-6855. Your credit card details and banking information. Your e-mail passwords and other account passwords.Your Facebook, Skype, AIM, ICQ and other.Call Apple Support +1-800-876-6855. Your private photos, family photos and other sensitive files.Your webcam could be accessed remotely by stalkers with a VPN virus.

`CC`: bar@example.com

`Message:` Apple Tech Support

**How do I remove this email and regain access to my browser?**

Comment: @Tetsujin It's a different question, but with the same answer.

Comment: hmmm...ok - not one I've come across. Guess I don't go down the rough end of the playground ;-)

Comment: Gotta love the ol' VPN virus :).

Comment: Hey there, did my answer help? If it did, do you mind accepting it with the checkmark button?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a website that repeatedly spawns email templates by repeatedly opening a new tab with a `mailto:` link, causing iOS to open email templates repeatedly. This is a known vulnerability in iOS, fixed in iOS 10.2.

To fix the issue without updating your software, go to `Settings` -> `Safari` -> `Clear Website and History Data`. Alternatively, on an iPhone 6S (or newer) with 3D Touch, you can force-press on the Safari icon, open a `New Tab`, then immediately press down and hold the tab switcher icon, and hit `Close All Tabs`.

[Learn more about this issue.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7599373?start=0&tstart=0)

**Note:** This is fixed in iOS 10.2 (which, sadly, your iPad 2 can't update to), which prevents websites from opening `mailto:` links until the user specifically approves it.